# BrokenPipeError between DataFlow and BigQuery using Python Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a pipeline that is using Apache Beam in DataFlow. We have the same configuration in multiple regions that works perfectly but in europe-west1 we have connection problems between DataFlow and BigQuery.

Here is the exception we're receiving:

```
"Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 263, in wrapper
    sleep_interval = next(retry_intervals)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 510, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 516, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1681, in finish_bundle
    return self._flush_all_batches()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1691, in _flush_all_batches
    for destination in list(self._rows_buffer.keys())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1692, in <listcomp>
    if self._rows_buffer[destination]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1725, in _flush_batch
    skip_invalid_rows=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 1253, in insert_rows
    project_id, dataset_id, table_id, rows, insert_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 266, in wrapper
    raise exn.with_traceback(exn_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 701, in _insert_all_rows
    timeout=BQ_STREAMING_INSERT_TIMEOUT_SEC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2678, in insert_rows_json
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 574, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 291, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 480, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 338, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 376, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 486, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 279, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 352, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 598, in do_instruction
    getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 635, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1001, in process_bundle
    op.finish()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 742, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 744, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 745, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1288, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1269, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1316, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 510, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 516, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1681, in finish_bundle
    return self._flush_all_batches()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1691, in _flush_all_batches
    for destination in list(self._rows_buffer.keys())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1692, in <listcomp>
    if self._rows_buffer[destination]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1725, in _flush_batch
    skip_invalid_rows=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 1253, in insert_rows
    project_id, dataset_id, table_id, rows, insert_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 266, in wrapper
    raise exn.with_traceback(exn_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 701, in _insert_all_rows
    timeout=BQ_STREAMING_INSERT_TIMEOUT_SEC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2678, in insert_rows_json
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 574, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 291, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 480, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 338, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 376, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 486, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
RuntimeError: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')) [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-50']
```

Did anyone already faced that kind of issue?

If you need more information please let me know

We've validate that the configuration is the same as the other environment

Comment: Sounds like something with networking. Is a VPC being used in that job? Are the network settings/firewall rules the same in europe-west1?

Comment: Could you please file a support ticket? We would need the Job ID to debug this further.

https://cloud.google.com/support-hub -> "File Support Case" -> https://console.cloud.google.com/support